# how to change map in specific language in android

Tags: dictionary

I want to know how to show map only in single language like hebrew or Hindi.
I have tried Locale but it change only few country language. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how old is your Android, in my HTC with an 2.2.3 There was no way of doing it.
You only have the languages that are on the list. eventually I ended up using
http://mynativemap.com/ It got the languages I needed, and it's good enough for now.